# Не находит сервлет

Tags: java, apache, servlet

Нужно создать веб приложение но почему то не видит сервлет
код сервлета:

```
    package com.example.demo;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Выдает:
[image: ошибка сервлета]

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
</web-app>
```

Comment: Попробуйте такую анотацию `@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", urlPatterns = {"/hello-servlet"})` Есть мнение, что `value` не работает, если используются другие параметры (`name` в данном случае). Кстати, можно проверить и такую `@WebServlet("/hello-servlet")`

Comment: попробовал, не помогло(

Comment: Возможно, дело в идее - нужно указать томкату, куда смотреть. Вы пользуетесь IntellijIDEA?

Comment: Так у Вас `web.xml` пустой. Tomcat же по нему и строит маршруты.

Comment: @Anastasiya да)

Comment: @МихаилМуругов так аннотация есть же)

Comment: @Dranik Вполне могу ошибаться, работал с этим давно и мало. Не помню, чтобы был какой-то способ через аннотации.

Comment: Покажите скрин пж) На скрине должна быть видна структура папок, и еще один скрин - сверху справа идеи есть папочка с синими кубиками - Project structure. Или как варик попробуйте удалить имя сервлета и оставить только `@WebServlet("/hello-servlet")`

Comment: @Anastasiya https://imgur.com/a/cTO19Xg

Comment: @Dranik Нуу зато сервлет теперь виден(если веб хмл вручную прописать)))) Покажите еще, пожалуйста, pom.xml. 
PS. томкат видит вашу веб-папку, будем разбираться

Comment: помимо pom, добавьте пж по какому урлу вы пытаетесь попасть на сервлет

Comment: @Anastasiya https://imgur.com/a/jh76hfg          ``` http://localhost:8080/demo_war_exploded/hello-servlet```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

1. Используя web.xml маппинг (не аннотации), заменить версию сервлетов на 4.0.0 и заменить плагин мавен на:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
             </plugin>
```

2. Если не сработает, плагин удали и удали строку из pom -> `<packaging>war</packaging>` - следите за тем чтобы папочка веб подсвечивалась синим кружком
3. Если и оно не сработает, аннотацию замени на просто `@WebServlet("/hello-sevlet")`

Если синий кружок потух, зайдите в Project structure - > Modules -> выбрать модуль\папку в которой ваш веб -> Web Resource Directory (на скрине красненьким светится) и указать путь к папке web (где лежит WEB INF)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все равно ошибка( Ну хоть сервлет видит но ошибку выкидывает и еще в pom.xml 3.6.1 версия плагина пишет что не найдена)

Comment: Лол, просто поставил 7 версию и все заработало)